# CSS mouse hover behaviour

Tags: css, mousehover

I have a table and want to highlight each line if cursor move over it.
So text color and background color should change.

Here is a minimized example:

```
<table>
    <tr class="line_0">
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>5</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="line_1">
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>5</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="line_0">
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>5</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="line_1">
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>5</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

and here is the css with the problem

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {    
   border: 2px dotted;
}
table .line_0 td {
   background: #FFF;
}
table .line_1 td {
   background: #EEE;
}
table .line_0:hover td,
table .line_1:hover td {
   color: #F00;
}
```

If you move your mouse over the second row and then back to the first, the border of second row will be still red. I tested under Firefox, but in Chrome its quite same behaviour. That problem occures only in these rows. Here you can test it: http://jsfiddle.net/47kZZ/16/

[image: fiddle screenshot]

After a lot playing around, I find a temporary fix by adding a color tag, which must necessarily be different, so nearly black.

```
table .line_0 td {
   color: #010100;
   background: #FFF;
}
table .line_1 td {
    color: #010000;
    background: #EEE;
}
```

So is it a common browser problem? Have you got a better fix? How does it look in IE?

Comment: Seems fine to me, tested with Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m

Comment: have you tried setting the color for your border? `border: 2px dotted #000;`

Comment: What **Pedro Estrada** said does the trick--add it to the :hover definition. And I'll just say, what a weird bug.

Comment: I also saw no problem with this, worked for me on chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 m and IE 10.

Comment: There is definitely a bug in chrome too. There it is the third row and it occur not each time. But border color fix it. Even it is strange, why different text color fix it for FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Short Form of border property and as per W3c, Border short hand property takes 3 properties. You have one property missing and hence the error.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands

```
4.4. Border Shorthand Properties
Name:   border-top, border-right, border-bottom, border-left
Value:  <line-width> || <line-style> || <color>
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/47kZZ/23/)